# sails-auth generators doesnt work

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js

I want to setup social authentication on my Sails app using [sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth) but my generator doesnt work.

here my .sailsrc

```
{
   "generators": {
   "modules": {
      "auth-api": "sails-auth"
   }
 }}
```

on terminal `sails generate auth-api` like the documentation, and this is the error `No generator called`auth-api`found; perhaps you meant`sails generate api auth-api?`

thanks for all

Comment: Have you installed the `sails-auth` package using `$ npm install sails-auth --save`?

Comment: yes i do, and i change the view engine from ejs to swig, i dont know if thats the problem.

Comment: Can you post a link to your project? I haven't seen this issue before. (I am the author of sails-auth)

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Clean install of latest sails and new project. Installed created .sailsrc as documented and get the same issue. RESOLVED. see below.

Comment: Did you solve this? I currently installed latest version. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My mistake was that I ran the "npm install sails-auth --save" command not in the newly generated sails project directory. See if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `sails-auth` you should configure `config/passport.js` and `config/auth.js`.
Try looking at [How to use sails-auth in sails project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194863/how-to-use-sails-auth-in-sails-project) this answer.