# How to use sails-auth in sails project?

Tags: sails.js, hook

How can I use sails-auth hook in my sails project? I installed sails-auth
using npm install sails-auth --save. and when running project terminal logs says sails-auth controllers, services, models are loaded using marlinspike. But I don't have any idea about further steps. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

`sails-auth` is a Passport-based User Authentication system for Sails.js applications.

When u run `npm install sails-auth --save`, it will install sails-auth as a Sails Hook. The Hook uses `marlinspike` to inject the relevant Controllers, Policies, etc into your Sails application, that why u got `sails-auth controllers, services, models are loaded using marlinspike`.

After installing `sails-auth` you should configure `config/passport.js` and `config/auth.js`.

Found a good step-by-step example [here](https://github.com/multunus/sails-auth-example)

Hope it helps.